# How to disable dynamically viewing div element?

Tags: javascript

I want to stop viewing a div element  that is dynamically will be add to the page.

My code is like this : 
if the `if statement` is `true`, stop viewing more div elements

How could I do that?

This function limit the check box ticking:

```
    function disableCheck() {
        document.getElementById("world").disabled = true;

}
    function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
        var checkgroup=checkgroup
        var limit=limit
        for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
            checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
            var checkedcount=0
            for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
                checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0

            if (checkedcount>limit) {
             disableCheck();
            this.checked=false;


                }

            }
        }
    }
```

For example we set the `limit` to 2. but after ticking the third `checkbox` it's not get checked sign but the `div` tag will be shown.

The full code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Checkboxes</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #00ff00; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".red").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".green").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $(".blue").toggle();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function disableCheck() {
    document.getElementById("world").disabled = true;

}
function disablediv() {
    document.getElementById("red").style.display = "none";


}

function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
    var checkgroup=checkgroup
    var limit=limit
    for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
        checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
        var checkedcount=0
        for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
            checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0

        if (checkedcount>limit) {
         disableCheck();
        this.checked=false;


            }

        }
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <form id="world" name="world">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> red</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green"> green</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue"> blue</label>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div class="red box" id="red">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.colorCheckbox, 2)

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean remove elements from DOM or preventing scroll ?

Comment: Can the div adder function be disabled somehow?

Comment: Then `ELEMENT.remove()` will help or `ELEMENT.style.style.display = 'none'` if you do not want to remove element from DOM but hide..

Comment: It will delete the element after it has been added. I want to forbid adding any element after the if statement.

Comment: @Vlad Can you please add your code here to show what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Vlad So you want to hide all the other checkboxes once the limit of the checkboxes allowed is reached? Else, please explain what you mean by "it's not get checked sign but the div tag will be shown."

Comment: @ShekharChikara That's work but it is not a complete solution

Comment: Please add your HTML code also, so that we can see which element you are trying to disable using the function disableCheck().

Comment: If you are including jQuery, it doesn't make sense to use things like `getElementById()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary : operator in Javascript to validate through Element.style.display.

```
ELEMENT.style.display = dosomething ? true : 'none'  ;
```

[Cool link about ternary operators (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)